# How can I save the BIOS CMOS or the UEFI BIOS settings of a notebook in a file and restore them if necessary?

Tags: bios, uefi, restore, cmos, save-as

Basic configuration settings of a PC are stored in the BIOS CMOS or in the UEFI BIOS. In DOS times there was a software called Checkit and QAPLUS, at least one of them could save the configuration of a BIOS CMOS in a file and save it back if needed.

Its also known the "Intel System Configuration Utility" offer like this in some cases. https://archive.is/ciaH9

How can I save the BIOS CMOS or the UEFI BIOS settings of a notebook in a file and restore them if necessary?

Comment: It's possible on some BIOS/UEFI. What is your computer ?

Comment: Its known they are BIOS versions which offers like this. But is asked for a software or a other general solution.

Comment: How can I save the BIOS CMOS or the UEFI BIOS settings of a notebook in a file and restore them if necessary? What the problem about?

Comment: Voting to reopen this question. It is not asking for subjective recommendation advice. Rather, it is describing a problem and looking for a specific solution to that problem. We should judge questions by the problem being posed instead of the presupposed answer. If the solution involves suggesting software, then that’s fine.